# Adding or deleting table rows with MySQL, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a script that removes row from table with MySQL and jQuery. Now I need to insert rows too. How should I modify the code?

**index.php**

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    while ($searchIds = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "<tr class='show'>
                  <td>".$searchIds["channel_name"]."</td>
                  <td>".$searchIds["customer_id"]."</td>
                  <td>
                      <a class='delete' href='#' id='".$searchIds['id']."' channel_id='".$searchIds["channel_name"]." ".$searchIds["customer_id"]."'>Delete id</a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

**.js**

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'deleteid=' + del_id;
        var channel_id = element.attr("channel_id");
        if(confirm("Delete?\n\n" + channel_id)){
            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                url     : "scripts/delete.php",
                data    : info,
                success : function(){}
            });
            $(this).parents(".show")
                .animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And delete.php has simple query for deleting row.

Comment: When do you want to add the row? I can see `delete` buttons, but I can't find any `add` button/s. BTW, you're asking how to insert a row in MySQL (mysql_query) or HTML table (jQuery)?

Comment: I have a text input on the row bottom and `add` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

**index.php**

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**js file**

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
                .........
    });
    $(".add").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type    : "POST",
          url     : "scripts/add.php",
          data    : { add your variables } 
          success : function(){}
               $('#myTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>');
          });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In your file add.php you can return a json array and read it to the new row .